# Python Pip doesn't work after updating to 19.3.1

Tags: python-3.x, pip, updates

After updating to the newest version of pip (19.3.1) with python 3.7.3, I can no longer use pip. When I run `pip install package`, I get the following error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. When trying to fix this error, I found that a common suggestion was running `python -m pip install package`. While this fixed my original problem, I get this different error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests._internal_utils'`. Keep in mind I am on Windows 10 If anyone can help me, it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guarantee a solution, here are a few suggestions to try:

```
pip3 install package
```

If that doesn't work:

```
python -m pip install package
```

If it still does not behave, try the following command which will reinstall pip.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

The final option is to uninstall python and reinstall your desired 64bit version of Python.

Comment: No, those solutions don't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When I did this, it told me which file I needed to add to my path. Thank you.